How to remove return to line in a list in a JSON file?
In Python, I would like to get all elements from my lists BIRD_answer and my_answer in a single row:
{
    "BIRD_answer":[
        [
            0.043478260869565216
        ],
        [
            0.07042253521126761
        ],
        [
            0.11363636363636363
        ]
    ],
    "my_answer":[
        [
            "MillenniumHighAlternative",
            0.043478260869565216
        ],
        [
            "RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)",
            0.07042253521126761
        ],
        [
            "DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)",
            0.11363636363636363
        ]
    ]
}

To give me a format like this :
    "BIRD_answer":[[0.043478260869565216],[0.07042253521126761],[0.11363636363636363]],
    "my_answer":[["MillenniumHighAlternative",0.043478260869565216],["RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)",0.07042253521126761],["DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)",0.11363636363636363]]
}

I have already tried to use jsbeautifier but doesn't work.

the json file will work just fine the way it is.  can you say why you want it to look like that?

Could you please provide your python code

@JohnGordon I face an issue when dealing with list of hundreds of values ... in term of readability

@KirillIlichev as my file is a list of elements here is my code using jsbeautifier ```with open(json_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
content = json.load(file)
    options = jsbeautifier.default_options()
    options.indent_size = 2
    
    for elem in content:
        print(elem)
        elem = jsbeautifier.beautify(json.dumps(elem), options)```


json files aren't typically meant to be read by humans.  If readability is the issue, then a better solution might be to use a json viewer/browser application.

You can do it using json.dumps
import json

data = {
    "BIRD_answer": [
        [0.043478260869565216],
        [0.07042253521126761],
        [0.11363636363636363]
    ],
    "my_answer": [
        ["MillenniumHighAlternative", 0.043478260869565216],
        ["RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)", 0.07042253521126761],
        ["DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)", 0.11363636363636363]
    ]
}

formatted_lines = []

for key, value in data.items():
    compact_value = json.dumps({key: value}, separators=(',', ':'))
    formatted_lines.append(f"    {compact_value[1:-1]}")

formatted_json = "{\n" + ",\n".join(formatted_lines) + "\n}"

print(formatted_json)

Result :
{
    "BIRD_answer":[[0.043478260869565216],[0.07042253521126761],[0.11363636363636363]],
    "my_answer":[["MillenniumHighAlternative",0.043478260869565216],["RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)",0.07042253521126761],["DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)",0.11363636363636363]]
}


This puts BIRD_answer and my_answer on the same line, which is not what they asked.

Thanks for your comment but i want BIRD_answer and my_answer on separate rowa, i want to get the data of each key on a single row but keeping the json structure

Oh, I see. I will update my answer more correctly soon.

Hi, @VictordeLeusse, I updated my answer so it will work with dynamic data and will return correct json format as you want.

Works well ! Congrats and thank you !

You will need to devise a custom formatter:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json

json_data = '''
{
  "BIRD_answer": [
    [0.043478260869565216],
    [0.07042253521126761],
    [0.11363636363636363]
  ],
  "my_answer": [
    ["MillenniumHighAlternative", 0.043478260869565216],
    ["RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)", 0.07042253521126761],
    ["DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)", 0.11363636363636363]
  ]
}
'''

def format_json(json_str: str, indent_char: str = ' ', indent_size: int = 4) -> str:
    parsed_data = json.loads(json_str)
    indent = indent_char * indent_size
    formatted_json = "{\n"
    for key, value in parsed_data.items():
        minified_value = json.dumps(value, separators=(',', ':'))
        formatted_json += f'{indent}"{key}": {minified_value},\n'
    return formatted_json.rstrip(',\n') + '\n}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(format_json(json_data))

This will result in:
{
    "BIRD_answer": [[0.043478260869565216],[0.07042253521126761],[0.11363636363636363]],
    "my_answer": [["MillenniumHighAlternative",0.043478260869565216],["RanchodelMarHigh(Continuation)",0.07042253521126761],["DelAmigoHigh(Continuation)",0.11363636363636363]]
}

Here is a more compact function:
def format_json(json_str: str, indent_char: str = ' ', indent_size: int = 4) -> str:
    parsed_data, indent = json.loads(json_str), indent_char * indent_size
    
    return "{\n" + "\n".join(
        f'{indent}"{key}": {json.dumps(value, separators=(",", ":"))},'
        for key, value in parsed_data.items()
    ).rstrip(',') + "\n}"


The issue there is that i will loose my data types

@VictordeLeusse what data types? The input JSON you provided was converted to the desired output JSON?

My bad after few adaptations it works well !!!
